# XdmNode line number and column

Tags: c#, xml, saxon

I need to get the line number and the column in the source document from a XdmNode. I know I can do this with:

```
XmlNode n = (XmlNode)((VirtualNode)node.Unwrap()).getUnderlyingXmlNode();
IXmlInfo xInfo = (IXmlInfo)n;
int line = xInfo.LineNumber;
int col = xInfo.LinePosition;
```

But node.Unwrap() is an object from type net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyElementImpl and that cannot be casted to a VirtualNode, maybe because I don´t load the document with DocumentBuilder.Wrap(XmlDocument) but DocumentBuilder.Build(XmlReader)?

The method with XmlReader is way faster than the XmlDocument version. How can I get the line number and column from the XdmNode?

Comment: Thanks for reporting the bug. We are currently investigating issue. It have filed a bug issue here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2834

Comment: Fix committed and available in the next maintenance release of Saxon

Answer (score 0):

To add to O'Neil's response:

(a) XdmNode on .NET does not have LineNumber and ColumnNumber properties, unlike its Java equivalent. We will add these. But of course the properties will only return anything useful if line number information is available.

(b) In the absence of these properties, you can use XdmNode.Implementation.getLineNumber() and XdmNode.Implementation.getColumnNumber().

(c) Line/column information will not be maintained unless the IsLineNumbering property is set on the DocumentBuilder.

(d) with the above caveats, line/column numbering should work if you build the document from a Uri or a Stream or a TextReader, with default configuration options (specifically, if the built-in Xerces parser is used to parse the XML document)

(e) when an XmlReader is used to parse the document, there is Saxon code that attempts to get the line/column information from the MS parser into the Saxon-constructed node, but our initial tests suggest it may not be working.